# Open a new tab in browser with custom html code. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I have a function that opens a new tab in the browser with custom html that is generated in the root tab?

Comment: How about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/3569921

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
var x=window.open();
x.document.open().write('<h1>Test</h1>');
x.close();
```

Note that you cannot force it to be a new tab as that is a user preference (of new window / new tab)